# Why iOS platform can use Firebase/Firestore without google service?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I know in Android Firebase requires google service component, but why Firebase works fine in iOS even though iOS doesn't have google service.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Google play services built into iOS devices.  Unlike Android, the Firebase iOS SDKs provide all their own implementations of Firebase Authentication and other Firebase products.  Google can require device manufacturers to include Play services on their Android devices (which is necessary to make the Play store work), but it obviously can't require Apple to preload any similar software.